# Differnce between interface refrence and concrete class reference

Tags: java, collections

I want to ask a question about using `List` in Collections API of java :

```
List <Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<Integer> aList = new ArrayList<>();
```

We can use either for making an object of `ArrayList`, so which is the better way to create an `ArrayList`, and why?

Answer (score 2):

The first option makes the rest of your code more modular, since you can replace the List implementation used by your code by changing a single line of code.

You'd just have to change

```
List <Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
```

to

```
List <Integer> list = new SomeOtherListImplementation<>();
```

Declaring the variable to be ArrayList ties your code to the ArrayList implementation of the List interface.

If, however, your code requires usage of methods of ArrayList that are not part of the List interface, you might have to use an ArrayList variable.

Answer (score 0):

The first case called as [programming to interfaces](http://codeinventions.blogspot.in/2014/10/programming-with-interface-and-programming-to-interface-in-java-difference.html).

If you stick to interface programming and implement your programm later you may change it to some other implementation.

For ex

```
List <Integer> list = new LinkedList<>();
```

If you code in first way, when ever you need to change just change the Right Hand Side of the initialization part and you are done without any code breakage and without any compiler error.

Answer (score 0):

```
ArrayList<Integer> aList = new ArrayList<>();
```

Above line of code is ok if the variable aList is not modified later.

```
List <Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
```

But if you want to add more flexibility to your code I would suggest this way because you can later declare the list variable to a different List implementation.

```
List <Integer> list = new LinkedList<>();
```

It will not break the code because it ensures that you only call the methods that are defined by the List interface.

Answer (score 0):

First approach is modular. Which is taking advantage of fact that "**Base class pointer can point to Derived class Object**".

This is particularly helpful while we are passing argument. say,

```
public void display(List<String> names);

LinkedList<String> names = new LinkedList<String>();
display(names);
```